# React-typing-animation is not re-rendered when state is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I have the following component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Typing from "react-typing-animation";

export class InfoDisplayer extends Component {
  infos = ["this is a test", "this is another test"];

  updateDisplayedInfo() {
    if (this.state.currentIndex >= this.infos.length) {
      this.setState({
        currentInfo: this.infos[0],
        currentInfo: 0,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex + 1,
        currentInfo: this.infos[prevState.currentIndex + 1],
      }));
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentInfo: this.infos[0],
      currentIndex: 0,
    };

    this.updateDisplayedInfo = this.updateDisplayedInfo.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Typing onFinishedTyping={this.updateDisplayedInfo}>
        {this.state.currentInfo}
      </Typing>
    );
  }
}

export default InfoDisplayer;
```

I'm using https://github.com/notadamking/react-typing-animation which is a component used for getting a text typing animation. It has a handler called `onFinishedTyping` which can be used to do something after the typing is done. I'm using it to change my component state to update the current info state.

Although that `updateDisplayedInfo` is called and `currentInfo` is updated, the component is not rendered again.

Why? I believe `setState` should re-render the component.

**Addition**: online code
[image: Edit epic-surf-b7pgy]

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11872246/keikai edit, you can use the react dev tools to see that the state has been changed after the first typing animation

Comment: I am sorry didn't see it properly. Does the function runs either of those conditions?

Comment: Yes,
On first render, "this is a test" is written, the function is called and enter in the second condition, state is changed to "this is another test" but nothing happens afterwards

Comment: Hmm... strange behavior. I am trying to look what's going wrong with it atm.

Comment: Also, If you change your library version to `1.3.0` Your problem gets solved. It seems like a bug in a recent version. You check it out here - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-morning-eww89 . Library is probably not maintained by the creator anymore.

Comment: Look what happens when you render ```<div>
        <Typing onFinishedTyping={() => updateText()}>
          {this.state.currentInfo}
        </Typing>
        <Typing onFinishedTyping={() => updateText()}>
          {this.state.currentInfo}
        </Typing>
      </div>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notice points:

- Add loop
- Add `Typing.Reset`

Refer to document [here](https://github.com/notadamking/react-typing-animation#reset-component)

[image]

---

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Typing from "react-typing-animation";

import "./styles.css";

const infos = ["this is a test", "this is another test"];

export class InfoDisplayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.currentIndex);
  }

  updateDisplayedInfo = () => {
    this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Typing onFinishedTyping={this.updateDisplayedInfo} loop>
        {infos[this.state.currentIndex]}
        <Typing.Reset count={1} delay={500} />
      </Typing>
    );
  }
}

export default InfoDisplayer;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <InfoDisplayer />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit elated-einstein-ncc7q]